# PHP Script to Force Download Not Working

Tags: php, apache, permissions, http-status-code-403

I had a simple little php code that allowed me to force users to download videos from my site rather than playing it in the browser

```
<?php

$path = $_GET['path'];
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($path));
readfile($path);

?>
```

Since I moved my site to a new server, there seems to be a permission problem where I am getting a **403 Forbidden "You don't have permission to access /download-stream.php on this server."**

the php file is set to the same permissions as before (644). I'm not sure why it's doing this now.

Comment: The Apache config (httpd.conf) caused the permission problem. Try uploading a hello world script, does it work?

Comment: what are the permissions of root folder?

Comment: I hope you've just simplified that for our benefit, because that is some extremely exploitable code right there...

Comment: Hello world works. Root folder has 755 permissions (a wordpress blog is installed on it), and to Darien, I'm quite an amateur at php and that is in fact the entirety of the download php script....I guess I should be embarrassed

Comment: Do you need a workaround for the `403` error or do you need help with the download script?

Answer (score 1):

I generally use something like this to force downloads. Remember to change MIME type if you change the type of file being downloaded.

```
        $attachment_location = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/file.zip";
        if (file_exists($attachment_location)) {

            header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 200 OK");
            header("Cache-Control: public"); // needed for i.e.
            header("Content-Type: application/zip");
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
            header("Content-Length:".filesize($attachment_location));
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.zip");
            readfile($attachment_location);
            die();        
        } else {
            die("Error: File not found.");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$path\"\n");
$fp=fopen("$path", "r");
fpassthru($fp);
```

?>