# Read network-configuration with PHP

Tags: php, regex, networking

PHP knows the own IP in `$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]` but how can I read the rest of the network-configuration netmask, broadcast, etc?

One solution would be to get the information with exec on my Linux server, but that would be quite a complicated regular expression to cut that information apart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu:

```
exec("/sbin/ifconfig", $data);
$data = implode($data, "\n");

foreach (preg_split("/\n\n/", $data) as $int) {
  preg_match("/^([A-z]*\d)\s+Link\s+encap:([A-z]*)\s+HWaddr\s+([A-z0-9:]*).*" .
    "inet addr:([0-9.]+).*Bcast:([0-9.]+).*Mask:([0-9.]+).*" .
     "MTU:([0-9.]+).*Metric:([0-9.]+).*" .
     "RX packets:([0-9.]+).*errors:([0-9.]+).*dropped:([0-9.]+).*overruns:([0-9.]+).*frame:([0-9.]+).*" .
     "TX packets:([0-9.]+).*errors:([0-9.]+).*dropped:([0-9.]+).*overruns:([0-9.]+).*carrier:([0-9.]+).*" .
     "RX bytes:([0-9.]+).*\((.*)\).*TX bytes:([0-9.]+).*\((.*)\)" .
     "/ims", $int, $regex);

    if (!empty($regex)) {
      $interface = array();

      $interface = array(); 
      $interface['name'] = $regex[1]; 
      $interface['type'] = $regex[2]; 
      $interface['mac'] = $regex[3]; 
      $interface['ip'] = $regex[4]; 
      $interface['broadcast'] = $regex[5]; 
      $interface['netmask'] = $regex[6]; 
      $interface['mtu'] = $regex[7]; 
      $interface['metric'] = $regex[8]; 

      $interface['rx']['packets'] = $regex\[9]; 
      $interface['rx']['errors'] = $regex\[10]; 
      $interface['rx']['dropped'] = $regex\[11]; 
      $interface['rx']['overruns'] = $regex\[12]; 
      $interface['rx']['frame'] = $regex\[13]; 
      $interface['rx']['bytes'] = $regex\[19]; 
      $interface['rx']['hbytes'] = $regex\[20]; 

      $interface['tx']['packets'] = $regex\[14]; 
      $interface['tx']['errors'] = $regex\[15]; 
      $interface['tx']['dropped'] = $regex\[16]; 
      $interface['tx']['overruns'] = $regex[17]; 
      $interface['tx']['carrier'] = $regex[18]; 
      $interface['tx']['bytes'] = $regex[21]; 
      $interface['tx']['hbytes'] = $regex[22];

      $interfaces[] = $interface;
    }
}
```

**Source:** Regular Expression Pattern Parsing ifconfig

http://www.highonphp.com/regex-pattern-parsing-ifconfig

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `exec()` function to run ipconfig or ifconfig depending on your server and if you have permission or not. You will then need to scrape the results from the returned array of strings.

```
exec('ifconfig',$output); //use ipconfig for windows
print_r($output);
```

If you don't want to us `ifconfig` you could create a custom script that you can still use `exec()` with but that has cleaner output for easier manipulation.

Comment: You might want to point out the dangers of using `exec()` and the fact that if the server is a shared host they most likely won't have access to it

Comment: @RMcLeod Yeah I completely agree, that is why I said "If you have permission".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197845/how-should-i-or-should-i-use-php-functions-considered-dangerous